# Why load_textdomain work but not load_plugin_textdomain?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multi-language, localization, language

In my plugin's `init` function

```
    load_textdomain( 'myplugin', ABS_PATH_TO_MO_FILE ); // OK

    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false,  ABS_PATH_TO_LANGS_DIR); // No effect

    echo( __('Test', 'myplugin') );
```

In the code above, the load_textdomain works, but not load_plugin_textdomain, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](http://queryposts.com/function/load_plugin_textdomain/) `load_plugin_textdomain` takes three arguments:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( $domain, $abs_rel_path = false, $plugin_rel_path = false )
```

It seems you are passing the absolute path to your language domain, as a relative path. Try:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', ABS_PATH_TO_LANGS_DIR);
```